# Loop first run continue in shell script

Tags: shell, loops, continue

How to break out of infinite `while` loop in a shell script?

I want to implement the following `PHP` code in shell script(s):

```
$i=1; 
while( 1 ) {
  if ( $i == 1 ) continue;
  if ( $i > 9 ) break;
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: Since your code checks if $i == 1, and continues to the next iteration if the result is true, before incrementing $i, you actually hava an endless loop.

Comment: You have an endless loop in your php code.

Answer (score 1):

`break` works in shell scripts as well, but it's better to check the condition in the `while` clause than inside the loop, as Zsolt suggested. Assuming you've got some more complicated logic in the loop before checking the condition (that is, what you really want is a `do..while` loop) you can do the following:

```
i=1
while true
do
    if [ "$i" -eq 1 ]
    then
        continue
    fi
    # Other stuff which might even modify $i
    if [ $i -gt 9 ]
    then
        let i+=1
        break
    fi
done
```

If you really just want to repeat something `$count` times, there's a much easier way:

```
for index in $(seq 1 $count)
do
    # Stuff
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=1
while [ $i -gt 9 ] ; do
     # do something here 
     i=$(($i+1))
done
```

Is one of the ways you can do it.

HTH